# Symfony 4 trying to load HTML purifier from a custom controller

Tags: php, symfony

From the code below I am trying to use HTML purifier to clean some text but I get error

`Attempted to load class "HTMLPurifier_Config" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?`

I am using a use statement in `HTMLPurifierController` and PHP Storm is not giving any error so not sure why ? I even used the automatic class import and that worked fine. Do I have to do something else ?

my file tree is like this:

```
root
  -> HTMLPurifier
  -> src
     -> Controller
        -> user
           -> UserMessagesController
        -> util
           -> HTMLPurifierController
```

HTMLPurifierController

```
namespace App\Controller\util;

use HTMLPurifier;
use HTMLPurifier_Config;

class HTMLPurifierController
{

  /**
   * @param $string
   * @return string
   */
  static function HTMLpurifier($string){

    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($string);

    return $clean_html;

  }

}
```

UserMessagesController

```
use App\Controller\util\HTMLPurifierController;

......

$msgClean = HTMLPurifierController::HTMLpurifier($msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $config = \HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $purifier = new \HTMLPurifier($config);
    $clean_html = $purifier->purify($string);
    return $clean_html;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Comment: I just copied the directory to the root

Answer (score 2):

You may do better with the [HTMLPurifierBundle](https://github.com/Exercise/HTMLPurifierBundle). It creates Symfony services, form-types and filters.

With it, you can just type-hint `\HTMLPurifier $htmlPurifier` in a service, and then use it - `echo $htmlPurifier->purify('<html ...>');`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, can't accept because it does not answer the question but I'll definitely check it out

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer because this is both replies from @Tsv and @Alister_Bulman that lead me to get it working.

Two things:

- as Suggested by TsV, HTML purifier was not installed properly so I deleted my HTMLPurifier folder from the root.
- Then I installed using Alister suggestion the Symfony Purifier Bundle `composer require exercise/htmlpurifier-bundle`

Code works fine now